# Is there a way to do repeated measure ANOVA in gtsummary

Tags: gtsummary

I have data similar to the following data. My data is Normally distributed and would like to do a repeated measure ANOVA using gtsummary. Is that possible?

```
smpl <-
  structure(list(Participant.ID = c(1002, 1007, 1010, 1017, 1018, 
                                    1022, 1044, 1050, 1051, 1052, 1002, 1007, 1010, 1017, 1018, 1022, 
                                    1044, 1050, 1051, 1052, 1002, 1007, 1010, 1017, 1018, 1022, 1044, 
                                    1050, 1051, 1052), Randomization = c("Pioglitazone", "Pioglitazone", 
                                                                         "Pioglitazone", "Pioglitazone", "Pioglitazone", "Pioglitazone", 
                                                                         "Pioglitazone", "Pioglitazone", "Pioglitazone", "Pioglitazone", 
                                                                         "Pioglitazone", "Pioglitazone", "Pioglitazone", "Pioglitazone", 
                                                                         "Pioglitazone", "Pioglitazone", "Pioglitazone", "Pioglitazone", 
                                                                         "Pioglitazone", "Pioglitazone", "Pioglitazone", "Pioglitazone", 
                                                                         "Pioglitazone", "Pioglitazone", "Pioglitazone", "Pioglitazone", 
                                                                         "Pioglitazone", "Pioglitazone", "Pioglitazone", "Pioglitazone"
                                    ), Day = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                                         2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
                                                         3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("0", "3", "7"), class = "factor"), 
                 value = c(31.92, 53.25, 34.69, 33.32, 25.94, 34.69, 22.65, 
                           33.32, 24.33, 25.94, 31.92, 46.54, 44.74, 145.12, 37.34, 
                           39.89, 22.65, 27.5, 25.94, 25.94, 37.34, 53.25, 29.02, 37.34, 
                           25.94, 34.69, 22.65, 27.5, 29.02, 31.92)), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                    -30L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I have tried using R but not gtsummary.

Comment: You can do repeated measures ANOVA via lme4 in gtsummary. https://www.danieldsjoberg.com/gtsummary/reference/tests.html

Comment: Hi Daniel. Still haven't figured it out how to use lme4 to do the repeated ANOVA. Not sure of the syntax. Any tip will be appreciated. Thanks